# Corona Lua Profiler

Tags: lua, profiling, profiler, coronasdk

I'm making some games using the Lua Corona SDK and am trying to optimize my code. Is there a free profiler that I can use to focus my optimization attention?

I see there is a tool called Corona Profiler, but it costs some money. Can I use standard Lua Profilers? Are there any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Corona Profiler unfortunately, or write your own, standard lua profilers that I tested have some need or other that Corona does not provide, or they don't profile some things correctly (ie: Corona Obj-C/Java code running doing things, specially on GPU).

I bought Corona Profiler myself, and I must say it is kinda good, not excellent, but it helps a bit.

Granted, I think if you write your own profiler you will not match Corona Profiler easily, they did some extensive reverse engineering of Corona to figure the meaning of some stuff (and I think they did that with Coronalabs blessing)